# Updating an exisiting Sharepoint View using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm using PowerShell to create/update standard views in SharePoint 2010.
I've created an XML file that contains the View info, and use the below function in powershell to create the view based on the xml file.

The function works great to add new views, but what I want add is that if the view already exists, update it with the info from the xml file.

So basically, create the views, else update them instead.

```
 ForEach($xmlView in $xml.Root.Views.SelectNodes("View"))
 {
    $title = Get-XmlElement-Text $xmlView.SelectSingleNode("Title");
    $spView = $lib.Views[$title];
    if($spView -eq $null)
    {
        $Error.Clear(); #Need to clear Errors to handle non terminating errors

        $defaultView = Get-XmlElement-Text $xmlView.SelectSingleNode("DefaultView");
        if($defaultView -ne $null)
        {
            $defaultView = [boolean]::parse($defaultView);
        }
        else
        {
            $defaultView = $false
        }

        $rowLimit = Get-XmlElement-Text $xmlView.SelectSingleNode("RowLimit");
        if($rowLimit -eq $null)
        {
            $rowLimit = 100;
        }

        $paged = Get-XmlElement-Text $xmlView.SelectSingleNode("Paged");
        if($paged -ne $null)
        {
            $paged = [boolean]::parse($paged);
        }
        else
        {
            $paged = $true
        }

        $sortFilter = $xmlView.SelectSingleNode("SortFilter").InnerXML;

        $viewFields = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection;

        foreach($xmlField in $xmlView.ViewFields.SelectNodes("Field"))
        {
            $f = Get-XmlElement-Text $xmlField
            if($f -ne $null -and $lib.Fields.ContainsField($f) -eq $true)
            {
                $viewFields.Add($f) > $null;
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Error "failed to find field: [$f] in library: [$lib]";
                break;
            }

        }
        if($Error.Count -eq 0)
        {
            $lib.Views.Add($title, $viewFields, $sortFilter, $rowLimit, $paged, $defaultView) > $null;
            Write-Verbose "Added view: [$title] to libary $($lib.title)" -verbose;

        }
        else
        {
            Write-Warning "Failed to add view: [$title] to libary $($lib.title)";
        }


    }
    else
    {


      Write-Host "Duplicate view found: [$spView]";

      #If View already exists, update instead

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dunno why this was downvoted,  but here's the answer if you havn't got it already.

you already have the view in your $spView field,  so just call the following methods

```
$spView.ViewFields.Add("newfieldname1");
$spView.ViewFields.Add("newfieldname2");

//this can be a loop to add as many as you want

$spView.ViewFields.Delete("Removefieldname1");

//again can be a loop

//then finish by calling the update method

$spView.Update();
```